# ... may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

**Entity Framework Core**

Throwing error while doing update-database

**Error:-** 
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRoels_ParentUserRoleId' on table 'UserRoleRelationship' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index.

```
public class UserRoleRelationship 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid UserRoleRelationshipId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole ChildUserRole { get; set; }
    public int ChildUserRoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole ParentUserRole { get; set; }
    public int ParentUserRoleId { get; set; }

}

public class UserRole 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { set; get; }
    public int RoleId { set; get; }
    public virtual U.User User { set; get; }
    public int UserId { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Throwing error while doing update-database Error: may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

Comment: I have more than 10 models, which model has FK for that show this error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your current model design, it will create migration below:

```
            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRole_ChildUserRoleId",
            table: "UserRoleRelationship",
            column: "ChildUserRoleId",
            principalTable: "UserRole",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRole_ParentUserRoleId",
            table: "UserRoleRelationship",
            column: "ParentUserRoleId",
            principalTable: "UserRole",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

`FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRole_ChildUserRoleId` and `FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRole_ParentUserRoleId` both will delete the records in `UserRole` when deleting `UserRoleRelationship` which will cause multiple cascade delete.

For a workaround, try to make `int` as `int?` like below:

```
        public int? ParentUserRoleId { get; set; }
```

Which will create

```
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_UserRoleRelationship_UserRole_ParentUserRoleId",
                table: "UserRoleRelationship",
                column: "ParentUserRoleId",
                principalTable: "UserRole",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

**Note**
You need to delete `UserRole` first, then delete `UserRoleRelationship`

Comment: I believe you need to delete the `UserRoleRelationship` first, then delete the `UserRole`. The `Restrict` will prevent the `UserRole` delete if there exists a `UserRoleRelationship` that references it.

Comment: I set `onDelete` with `NoAction` for the second foreign key. It works.

Answer (score 3):

For a workaround, try to make `int` as `int?` like below:

`public int? ParentUserRoleId { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Additionally, on the **virtuals** (e.g. `virtual Role Role`) declare `[Key, ForeignKey("... foreign key field name ...")]` , i.e. in the example: `[Key, ForeignKey("RoleId")] virtual Role Role { get; set; }`. That way, the migration is created with the correct navigation properties.

Comment: Perfect Matt , Keep it up

Comment: By the way - your answer saved my day. Thank you!